# NSData内にあるバイトデータを構造体へのポインタとしてアクセスするには

Tags: swift

UnsafeMutablePointer型を何とか利用して
構造体へのキャストもできるのではと考えたのですが、
下記のようにした場合、
(1)：構造体を初期化
(2)：構造体のポインタを取得
その後、(3)のようにしてみたもののmyptrにdataが設定されませんでした。
何か良い方法はないのでしょうか。

## C言語のヘッダーファイル

```
typedef struct {
u_char test1;
u_char test2;
u_char test3[2];
} TEST_STR;
```

## swiftソース

```
func casttest(data: NSData) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<TEST_STR> {
    var test = TEST_STR()   // (1)
    var myptr = withUnsafeMutablePointer(&test){$0}   // (2)

    // myptr.memory.test1　で参照できた（初期化しているので値は0）

    data.getByte(&myptr, length: sizeof(TEST_STR)    // (3)

    return myptr
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

すいません、下記の方法でキャストできました。
他にも方法ある、こんなやり方じゃだめ！など意見もらえると嬉しいです。

```
func casttest(data: NSData) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<TEST_STR> {
    var test = TEST_STR()   // (1)
    data.getByte(&test, length: sizeof(TEST_STR)    // (3)
    var myptr = withUnsafeMutablePointer(&test){$0}   // (2)

    return myptr
}
```

Comment: まったくダメです。あなたが最後にreturnしている`myptr`は、`test`のアドレス(運が良ければ、ですが。言語仕様上は保障はありません)を指しており、`test`はローカル変数ですから、`casttest`の実行終了時にその領域は解放されるため、一旦解放されて(後で他の用途に使われる)領域を指していることになります。動作チェックのタイミングによっては動いているように見えることがあるかもしれませんが、まったく使い物にはなりません。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
そのとおりでした。ポインタとは…の概念がすでに抜けておりました。

Answer (score 1):

NSData内にあるバイトデータを構造体へのポインタとしてアクセスしたいのであれば、これだけでポインタを取得できます。

```
func casttest(data: NSData) -> UnsafePointer<TEST_STR> {
    return UnsafePointer<TEST_STR>(data.bytes)
}
```

元の`data`がどこかの変数に保持されている限り解放された領域を指してしまう心配もありません。ただし、NSData内のデータは書き換え不可です。
　データの中身を書き換える可能性があるのならば、NSMutableDataにコピーしてから使うという手もあるのですが、必要な有効範囲を持った変数にさっさとコピーする方が楽でしょう。

```
func mutablecasttest(data: NSData) {
    var test_str = casttest(data).memory
    //test_str(TEST_STR型になります)を使った処理...
}
```

できれば必要もないのにポインターを使うことは避けた方が良いのですが、どうしても使わなければいけない場合でも、解放された領域を指してしまっている宙ぶらりんポインターを作らないようにするべく、細心の注意を払ってください。また構造体の各メンバーのメモリ上における物理配置に依存したコードにすることの危険性についてはくれぐれも理解しておいてください。
　また、タイトルの「NSDataを構造体にキャスト」は不適切なので(NSData型はNSData型であり、構造体に型変換することはできません)、できればより適切なタイトルへの変更を考えてみてください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
まさにUnsafePointer<TEST_STR>(data.bytes)が実施したかったです。
ですが、「必要な有効範囲を持った変数にさっさとコピーする方が楽でしょう。」こちらのほうを使用させていただきたいと思います！
大変勉強になりました。
件名修正いたしました。